# How to do <title> dynamic in PHP

Tags: php, html, dynamic, page-title

I have a little template and in this template I have a query from database.

The name of the page is test.php and the code is:

This is the main page where i echo the content is named test.php

```
<?php include "components/header.php"; ?>

<div class="container">

    <!-- Jumbotron -->

    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['user']))
    {
        $user = $_GET['user'];
    }
    else
    {
        die("Not found");
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES utf8");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fk_music=".$user;
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $query); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);


    echo $row['text'];?>

</div>

<?php include "components/footer.php"; ?>
```

Now with the `echo $row['text']` I have to echo all the content from the page, and in header.php are the data like `<html><header><title></title></header>` etc. How can I put a title foreach data from database dynamic?

There is the code from header.php

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>???</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/media-queries.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

     <!--Hover categorii -->
    <script src="/js/hover.js"></script>

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="/../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Now in database i have two rows id of the post and the row named text where is stored the HTML of all the page

Here is an example with content existing in row['text']

```
  <p class='style-title'>HERE IS THE THE TEXT I WANT TO PUT IT IN <title>  </p> 
      <div class='jumbotron'>
            <img class='img-responsive' src='/img/img.png'/>
</div>

         <div class='row'>
                <div class="col-lg-10 ">
                  <img class='img-responsive' src='/img/50.png' align='left' />

                  <p class='some-class'>Lorm ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Do the query before the include. Set a default value incase there is no record. Also use parameterized queries, this is open to SQL injections as is. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Ok but what can i get the title from each page..in the row['text'] i stored all the HTML and i have in page the title in body for each post but i don't know how to extract it cause it's hardcoded in every page for the post number one in body i have a paragraph like <p class="myclass"> There is my first title on body</p>...on the page number 2..is <p class="myclass"> There is my second title on body</p>..... Thanks for the suggestion with the parametrized queries.

Comment: How is `page1`, `page2`, etc built? via `$_GET['user']` or some other way? The `<title>` element is the title of the page. That is what is displayed in the tab/window of the browser. There can be only 1.

Comment: i use a template...it's the same page with different content..i generate content from databse by id..the title tag comes from <?php include "components/header.php"; ?>. And in this file header.php I need to put some PHP code in the <title> tag to put dyanmic title from my row['text'];

Comment: Store `row['text']` to a variable and include that variable in the `header.php`. There is no scope issue with `includes`, unless there are functions in the other file(s).

Comment: I can't to do that..cause in the row['text'] i have a lot of <p> with different classes...but there exist one paragraph i want to extract...the problem is ..i don't know how

Comment: I'm unclear what you are doing, can you update with more specific code?

Comment: Done! Hope it's more clear now..if not let me know please

Comment: I still don't know what you have.